# Cron job stops working while adding a function for order status change

Tags: event-observer, cron, magento-1.9.2.1

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and I am developing a custom extension.

Here is my config file of the extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <automatedstatus>
                <file>automatedstatus.xml</file>
            </automatedstatus>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <automatedstatus>
            <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_automatedstatus_resource</resourceModel>
        </automatedstatus>
        <vivasindustries_automatedstatus_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <automatedstatus>
            <table>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus</table>
            </automatedstatus>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_automatedstatus_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <automatedstatus_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </automatedstatus_setup>
        <automatedstatus_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </automatedstatus_read>
        <automatedstatus_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </automatedstatus_write>
    </resources>    
    <helpers>
        <automatedstatus>
            <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Helper</class>
        </automatedstatus>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <automatedstatus>
             <class>VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Block</class>
        </automatedstatus>
    </blocks>
  </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <automatedstatus>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>automatedstatus/observer::setStatus</model>
                </run>
            </automatedstatus>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>  
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <automatedstatusadmin>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </automatedstatusadmin>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>  
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

For developing purpose, I have set the cron job to run every minute.
Here is my observer.php:

```
class VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model_Observer
{
   public function setStatus() {
        Mage::log("The order status was changed!");
    }
}
```

Every minute I can see that the cron job is done by seeing that `The order status was changed!` message is added to my system.log file.

However when I change it to this:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model_Observer
{
   public function setStatus() {

       try{ 
       $orderId = 100005082;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);
        $order->save();
        Mage::log("The order status was changed!");} 
       catch(Exception $e) 
       { 
       Mage::log($e->getMessage()); 
       } 

    }
}
```

In the system.log file there are no longer `The order status was changed!` message added and also the order status is not changed.

I am pretty sure the problem comes from the code for order status changing.

Where is my mistake? How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked your log files for the error ?

Comment: No errors at all...

Comment: Try to put your code within try and catch blocks like this:
try{ //your code } catch(Exception $e) { Mage::log($e->getMessage()); }

Delete old log files from /var/log folder and retest.

Comment: Do you have log settings ON from System >> Configuration >> Advanced (Developer) >> Log Settings?

Comment: Yes they are enabled.

Comment: I have updated my question. Is it what you want from me to do ?

Comment: I receive `2016-07-19T13:09:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): The Order State "complete" must not be set manually.` Why ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class VivasIndustries_AutomatedStatus_Model_Observer
{
   public function setStatus() {
        try {
             $orderId = "100005082";
             $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
             // $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);
             $order->addStatusHistoryComment("My comment why the status was changed", Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
             $order->save();
             Mage::log("The order status was changed!");
        } catch(Exception $exception) {
            Mage::logException($exception);
            Mage::log($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

try catch error in you save, and your orderId this `increment_id` and you need load order by attribute `increment_id` no `entity_id` for example `load($orderId,'increment_id')` or cal `loadByAttribute()` or `loadByIncrementId`.

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630707/magento-manually-change-order-status-to-complete

Comment: The error is: `2016-07-19T13:09:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): The Order State "complete" must not be set manually.` How can i fix that ?

Comment: @TonyStark I edit answer and see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630707/magento-manually-change-order-status-to-complete for fix it